# How to create a makefile for several .cpp files with .h files and main.cpp without a .h

Tags: c++, makefile

I have:

```
main.cpp 
distance.cpp
distance.h
adjacencyList.cpp
adjacencyList.h
```

Here is my makefile:

```
all: distance main adjacencyList
    g++ distance.o main.o adjacencyList.o

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp -lstdc++

adjacencyList.o: adjacencyList.cpp
    g++ adjacencyList.cpp -lstdc++

distance.o: distance.cpp
    g++ distance.cpp -lstdc++

clean:
    rm -rf *.o all
```

I am getting this error. So I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with main because it is not a class like the other two and does not have a .h file.

[image]

**Update:**

After trying Ben Voigt's solution I am getting 1 error:

[image]

Comment: Does the following command work? g++ distance.cpp adjacencyList.cpp main.cpp -lstdc++

Comment: No, I get bunch of warnings and then I get 3 errors : main.cpp:27: error asystema was not declared in this scope       main.cpp:70: error: aatoia was not declared in this scope

Comment: @Elephant: Then you need to add `#include <stdlib.h>` to main.cpp  After that, does it work?

Comment: Also, you eventually want to switch from `atoi()` to `strtol()`... the error handling is tons better.

Comment: I'm still getting a few warnings and 1 error (.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'main' Newline: collect2: ld returned 1` exit status

Comment: Your new error is in your code, not your makefile.  Your code is trying to pass a `std::string` to `open` on an `ifstream`, but `ifstream::open` in C++03 only takes `const char*`.  Give it a `const char*`, maybe using `c_str()`.  It could also be solved by adding `-std=c++11` to your CFLAGS -- I didn't do this in my answer because your question was not using that option.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is all working now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules to create object files are missing the `-c` option, for "compile only".  So they are trying to link, and failing because there is no `main()`.

Then, your `all` target names an executable for each of the compilation units.  Again, that's wrong because they don't all have `main()`.  You should have only one executable.  `all` should also be configured as a phony target, because it doesn't build an actual file named `all`.

All your rules are failing to control the name of the output file.

All your rules are failing to pass flags.

Your rules are missing dependencies on the headers, so editing headers won't cause the right files to be recompiled.

Really, you should get rid of the compile and link rules and let `make` use its built-in ones.  Focus on your build targets and dependencies.

Your end makefile should look something like this (of course, using spaces not tabs)

```
all : main

.PHONY : all clean

CC = g++
LD = g++

main : main.o adjacencyList.o distance.o

main.o: main.cpp adjacencyList.h distance.h

adjacencyList.o: adjacencyList.cpp adjacencyList.h

distance.o: distance.cpp distance.h

clean:
    rm -rf *.o main
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look over these points. Since I've only looked at make files for a few hours, I'm basically trying to get a simple makefile working for a homework.

Comment: I tried your solution and I am still getting one error that I am attempting to solve. It is in my updated question if you have time to look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: it is possible you are missing a semi-colon somewhere before including adjacencyList.h.
Check each header files and make sure each class definition is properly terminated with a semi-colon

Comment: Checked: my includes are all like 3rd-4th line down. So no semicolons missing.

Comment: Good catch Ben. I didn't pay attention to that

Comment: @elephant, aren't you missing some -c in your makefile (i.e. g++ -c distance.cpp for distance.o)?

Comment: no, I am using -lstdc++ instead of -c You can look at my make file in my question.